# class PortState(dict) meaning of inheritence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came across a python code given below.As I am new to Python,I was trying to understand the meaning of it.

```
class PortState(dict):
    # dict: int port_no -> OFPPort port
    # OFPPort is defined in ryu.ofproto.ofproto_v1_X_parser
    def __init__(self):
        super(PortState, self).__init__()

    def add(self, port_no, port):
        self[port_no] = port

    def remove(self, port_no):
        del self[port_no]

    def modify(self, port_no, port):
        self[port_no] = port
```

My current understanding is as follows.

Class PortState inherits from class dict?? is this correct.
In this case what is themember variable inside the class ? Is it a dictionary which maps
port_number(integer) to port (class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class PortState inherits from class dict?? is this correct.

Yes.

> In this case what is themember variable inside the class ?

I have little idea what this means, but I guess you might want to run `dir` on the class to see what attributes it has.

> Is it a dictionary which maps port_number(integer) to port (class)

It's instances can be, if you choose to use it like that. Note that it's sort of a silly class, because it's such a shallow wrapper around `dict` and it adds no functionality.